# Wordpress assigning the same post id to all new posts, thus the old content gets returned to the new post

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I create a new post, the post id remains the same, thus creating the same post again and again, Once I publish it, the old content gets copied to the new post. Thus am not able to create a new post at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It seems like this was because I was not clearing my cache from my browser.